# How to send utf-8 with json.dumps

Tags: python, json, utf-8

I have an issue and I need informations about to fixe.

I need to send a message with requests which is:

```
{'message': u'data:text/html,\xe9\xe9\xe9<br><br>\xe0\xe0\xe0<br>'}
```

To send it as json I use

```
json.dumps({'message': u'data:text/html,\xe9\xe9\xe9<br><br>\xe0\xe0\xe0<br>'})
```

This message is sent but on the platform the message is sent I have

```
Ã©Ã©Ã©

Ã Ã Ã
```

How can i get the ééé and àààà instead of Ã©Ã©Ã© and Ã Ã Ã ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending perfectly formed JSON. Python's `json` module will, by default, use JSON `\uhhhh` escapes for non-ASCII codes to avoid any transfer issues even:

```
>>> print json.dumps({'message': u'data:text/html,\xe9\xe9\xe9<br><br>\xe0\xe0\xe0<br>'})
{"message": "data:text/html,\u00e9\u00e9\u00e9<br><br>\u00e0\u00e0\u00e0<br>"}
```

It is the *receiving end* that is the problem here, you have what is called a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), an incorrect re-coding of the data. I can reproduce that by encoding to UTF-8, then decoding as Latin-1 or Windows codepage 1252, for example:

```
>>> print u'data:text/html,\xe9\xe9\xe9<br><br>\xe0\xe0\xe0<br>'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
data:text/html,Ã©Ã©Ã©<br><br>Ã Ã Ã <br>
```

There is nothing to be done on the Python end, fix the receiving end instead.

Comment: thanks for your response, I'm gonna check on osticket platform (http://osticket.com/) if there are some tips / help